# php xml dom extract data from non-standard xml

Tags: php, xml

Hello I have xml like this:

```
<specs><my>base</my><root>none</root></specs>
<books>

  <item>
    <id>14</id>
    <title>How to live</title>
  </item>

  <item>
    ...
  </item>

</books>
```

**How can I extract value from < my > ? and then < title >?**

when I have data such as :`<specs><my>base</my><root>none</root></specs>` in xml this code works for me. So how should I modify it to work with data such as books as well in xml?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entry = $xpath->query("//xml/specs/my");
foreach($entry as $ent){
  echo $ent->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean <books>, is that by your own Xml or with your <specs> together? clarify more...Paste the exact Xml you want to read

Comment: exact original xml is first xml in my question. when I remove everything between < books > and < /books > this php code works. But with my original xml posted on top php is not working (it does not read xml)

Comment: Your XML is not non-standard, it is just invalid (or incomplete). Also it is not clear what qualifies as a book in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply I added this:

```
$xml="<xml>".$xml."</xml>";
```

and now this works `$xpath->query("//xml/specs/my");` as well as `$xpath->query("//xml/books/item");`